# build list from array and allow list to be clickable

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to build and Android app:
How can I build a list on screen from an array and have the list be clickable?
with a value of the name to be able to use later stored in a String.

What I have now.

```
String game_list[] = {"game_0","game_2","game_3","game_3","game_4","game_5"};
    for(int i=0; i<game_list.length; i++){
    myText = myText + game_list[i] +"\n";
    }
    myTextView.setText("");
    myTextView.append(myText);
```

Comment: Use a JList with a DefaultListModel() if youre using swing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also you can use a spinner and adapter

`ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, game_list);         adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a super simple example that I have used: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/06/android-listview-tutorial-and-basic-example.html.

You basically need to make a listview object and add it to whatever view you happen to be using. Then you add "extends ListActivity" to the activity and add your list to the listactivity like so:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> directoryList = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.file_row, this.directoryEntries);
ListView fileList = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
fileList.setAdapter(directoryList);
```

Call:

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
```

to associate actions with your listview elements

Answer (score 0):

You can build that with `ListView` control in android and here very good tutorial about it to get more understand how to build it with the array or from any other  data source  like from database

```
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html
```

feed be back in any thing not obvious for you